# Problems using NHaml with ASP.NET MVC RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had no problems using NHaml with ASP.NET MVC Beta, but when upgrading to ASP.NET MVC RC I am getting a suspicious error

> Method 'FindPartialView' in type 'MvcContrib.NHamlViewEngine.NHamlViewFactory' from assembly 'MvcContrib.NHamlViewEngine, Version=0.0.1.175, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I inspected with reflector and the method is there.  Something else that may help is that when I refresh that error above I get a 404.  If I rebuild I get that error the first time and the 404 errors after.  Again this site was working unchanged in the beta.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you have the RC1 compatible versions of both MVCContrib and NHaml

For Nhaml
We have not done a "release version" with RC1 so you will need to build from source.
Any version after this (Jan 30) should be good
http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/source/detail?r=101

For MVC
Try the latest release (4 Feb)
http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22732

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix your error, but the FindPartialView method now takes an extra parameter, useCache, which is a boolean.  I don't know much about the NHaml view engine, but it appears that this error is causing your problem and that the MvcContrib will need to be updated for this.  Hopefully that helps you a little.